# AWS - "The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided" with IAM user and requests from python

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, python-requests, aws-api-gateway

I have an API in AWS API Gateway using POST method, which connects to AWS Lambda for some Poperations. And I need to invoke this code from Python-3.8 in an environment which will have nothing but standard library installed. So, I have found [these on AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-python-example_code-signv4.html) to sign requests to API Gateway.

Here's what I now have after trying to replicate things from the blogs and Postman.

```
# everything below is from
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/python-signv4-v4-signing-get-post.py.html

from datetime import datetime
import hashlib
import hmac
import json
import os
import requests
from requests.api import head

# initial parameters
method = "POST"
service = "execute-api"
region = "ap-south-1"
host = f"<my-api-id>.{service}.{region}.amazonaws.com"
endpoint = f"https://{host}/experiment-stage"


# set additional headers
content_type = "application/json"

# Read AWS Credentials from environment variables.
access_key = os.getenv('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_API_INVOKE')
secret_key = os.getenv('AWS_SECRTE_ACCESS_KEY_API_INVOKE')

# Create a date for headers and the credential string
t = datetime.utcnow()
amz_date = t.strftime("%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ")
date_stamp = t.strftime("%Y%m%d")  # Date w/o time, used in credential scope

# start creating canonical string.
canonical_uri = "/"

# request_parameters = json.dumps("{\"even\" : [1, 2, 3, 4], \"odd\" : [1, 2, 3, 4]}")
request_parameters = json.dumps("{\"even\" : [1,2,3,4], \"odd\" : [1,2,3,4]}")

canonical_querystring = ""

# Step 4: Create the canonical headers. Header names must be trimmed
canonical_headers = f"content-type:{content_type}\nhost:{host}\nx-amz-date:{amz_date}\n"

signed_headers = "host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date"


def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).digest()


def getSignatureKey(key, date_stamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(("AWS4" + key).encode("utf-8"), date_stamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, "aws4_request")
    return kSigning


# Step 6: Create payload hash. In this example, the payload (body of
# the request) contains the request parameters.
payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(request_parameters.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

# Step 7: Combine elements to create canonical request
# canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash
canonical_request = f"{method}\n{canonical_uri}\n{canonical_querystring}\n{canonical_headers}\n{signed_headers}\n{payload_hash}"

# ************* TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN*************
algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"
credential_scope = f"{date_stamp}/{region}/{service}/aws4_request"

# now sing the string
string_to_sign = f"{algorithm}\n{amz_date}\n{credential_scope}\n{hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()}\n"


# ************* TASK 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE *************
# Create the signing key using the function defined above.
signing_key = getSignatureKey(secret_key, date_stamp, region, service)

# Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
signature = hmac.new(signing_key, string_to_sign.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()


# ************* TASK 4: ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST *************
authorization_header = f"{algorithm} Credential={access_key}/{credential_scope}, SignedHeaders={signed_headers}, Signature={signature}"

headers = {"X-Amz-Content-Sha256": payload_hash,
           "X-Amz-Date": amz_date,
           "Content-Type": "application/json",
           "Host": host,
           "Authorization": authorization_header
           }

print(headers)

response = requests.request(method=method, url=endpoint, headers=headers, data=request_parameters)

print(f'Response code: {response.status_code}; Seconds Elapsed: {response.elapsed.total_seconds()};')
print(response.text)
```

And the error I get is:

```
$ /bin/python3 /home/naveen/.../with_requests_aws.py
{'X-Amz-Content-Sha256': '64cfb8d65af84614135d2de33dd26751ef2384f46579355de226c5062b2537e1', 'X-Amz-Date': '20210912T171926Z', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Host': '<my-api-id>.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com', 'Authorization': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<my-API-key-ID>/20210912/ap-south-1/execute-api/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=6a6fdb5bcf40a17ea6377b497ee28e9c8252899914b1348e87ab9876e6140b6d'}
Response code: 403; Seconds Elapsed: 0.530462;
{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'POST\n/experiment-stage\n\nhost:<my-api-id>.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-content-sha256:64cfb8d65af84614135d2de33dd26751ef2384f46579355de226c5062b2537e1\nx-amz-date:20210912T171926Z\n\nhost;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date\n64cfb8d65af84614135d2de33dd26751ef2384f46579355de226c5062b2537e1'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20210912T171926Z\n20210912/ap-south-1/execute-api/aws4_request\na48c1087cbce204f6f960dd7cebc064b8bd89022fba6644ccf4638eec4d65091'\n"}
```

Here it is working just as expected from Postman, when I add access key credentials in authorisation tab:
[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to manually sign the request? Use e.g. something like https://github.com/DavidMuller/aws-requests-auth instead. Or at least use it to debug / reverse engineer what it does vs. what your code does.

Comment: thanks for the reply, @luk2302.I can't install any additional package and have to use packages that come in standard python installation. I have gone through the code of that repo. I could understand from a quick look that the repo used botocore for credentials. And if using botocore or additional packages was an option for me, i would have used boto3 package instead of requests.

Comment: E.g. the `host` seems wrong since it still includes a `<my-api-id>` placeholder.

Comment: i have deliberately hidden it in code and error message to not publish them to stack overflow. if it was actually a place holder, error from aws would have been someylike api-stage doesn't exist or similar error and not signature mis-match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's what worked for me, specifically with AWS API Gateway for HTTP POST requests:

```
import requests
import json
from urllib.parse import quote, urlparse
import hmac
import hashlib
from datetime import datetime

def get_canonical_path(url):
    """
    Create canonical URI--the part of the URI from domain to query
    string (use '/' if no path)
    """
    parsedurl = urlparse(url)

    # safe chars adapted from boto's use of urllib.parse.quote
    # https://github.com/boto/boto/blob/d9e5cfe900e1a58717e393c76a6e3580305f217a/boto/auth.py#L393
    return quote(parsedurl.path if parsedurl.path else '/', safe='/-_.~')


def get_canonical_querystring(url):
    """
    Create the canonical query string. According to AWS, by the
    end of this function our query string values must
    be URL-encoded (space=%20) and the parameters must be sorted
    by name.
    This method assumes that the query params in `r` are *already*
    url encoded.  If they are not url encoded by the time they make
    it to this function, AWS may complain that the signature for your
    request is incorrect.
    It appears elasticsearc-py url encodes query paramaters on its own:
        https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/5dfd6985e5d32ea353d2b37d01c2521b2089ac2b/elasticsearch/connection/http_requests.py#L64
    If you are using a different client than elasticsearch-py, it
    will be your responsibility to urleconde your query params before
    this method is called.
    """
    canonical_querystring = ''

    parsedurl = urlparse(url)
    querystring_sorted = '&'.join(sorted(parsedurl.query.split('&')))

    for query_param in querystring_sorted.split('&'):
        key_val_split = query_param.split('=', 1)

        key = key_val_split[0]
        if len(key_val_split) > 1:
            val = key_val_split[1]
        else:
            val = ''

        if key:
            if canonical_querystring:
                canonical_querystring += "&"
            canonical_querystring += u'='.join([key, val])

    return canonical_querystring


def sign(key, msg):
    """
    Copied from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html
    """
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode('utf-8'), hashlib.sha256).digest()


def getSignatureKey(key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName):
    """
    Copied from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html
    """
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), dateStamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning


def get_headers(aws_host: str, url:str, body: str, aws_region:str, service:str, aws_access_key:str, aws_secret_access_key:str):
    # Create a date for headers and the credential string
    t = datetime.utcnow()
    amzdate = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
    datestamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d')  # Date w/o time for credential_scope

    canonical_uri = get_canonical_path(url)

    canonical_querystring = get_canonical_querystring(url)

    # Create the canonical headers and signed headers. Header names
    # and value must be trimmed and lowercase, and sorted in ASCII order.
    # Note that there is a trailing \n.
    canonical_headers = ('host:' + aws_host + '\n' +
                            'x-amz-date:' + amzdate + '\n')

    # Create the list of signed headers. This lists the headers
    # in the canonical_headers list, delimited with ";" and in alpha order.
    # Note: The request can include any headers; canonical_headers and
    # signed_headers lists those that you want to be included in the
    # hash of the request. "Host" and "x-amz-date" are always required.
    signed_headers = 'host;x-amz-date'

    payload_hash = hashlib.sha256(body).hexdigest()

    # Combine elements to create create canonical request
    canonical_request = ('POST' + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' +
                            canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers +
                            '\n' + signed_headers + '\n' + payload_hash)

    # Match the algorithm to the hashing algorithm you use, either SHA-1 or
    # SHA-256 (recommended)
    algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
    credential_scope = (datestamp + '/' + aws_region + '/' +
                        service + '/' + 'aws4_request')
    string_to_sign = (algorithm + '\n' + amzdate + '\n' + credential_scope +
                        '\n' + hashlib.sha256(canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())

    # Create the signing key using the function defined above.
    signing_key = getSignatureKey(aws_secret_access_key, datestamp, aws_region, service)

    # Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
    string_to_sign_utf8 = string_to_sign.encode('utf-8')
    signature = hmac.new(signing_key,
                            string_to_sign_utf8,
                            hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

    # The signing information can be either in a query string value or in
    # a header named Authorization. This code shows how to use a header.
    # Create authorization header and add to request headers
    authorization_header = (algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + aws_access_key +
                            '/' + credential_scope + ', ' + 'SignedHeaders=' +
                            signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature)

    headers = {
        'Authorization': authorization_header,
        'x-amz-date': amzdate,
        'x-amz-content-sha256': payload_hash,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }

    return headers



aws_host = '<api-id>.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com'
url = 'https://<api-id>.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/<my-endpoint>'

body = json.dumps({"key1":[<values>], "key2":[<values>]})
body = body.encode('utf-8')

aws_region = 'ap-south-1'
service = 'execute-api'

aws_access_key = '<access-key>'
aws_secret_access_key = '<secret-access-key>'

headers = get_headers(aws_host=aws_host, url=url, body=body, service=service,
                      aws_region=aws_region, aws_access_key=aws_access_key, aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)

print(headers)

response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=body)

print(response.status_code, response.text)
```