# How to access/invoke a sagemaker endpoint without lambda?

Tags: serverless, amazon-sagemaker

based on the aws documentation, maximum timeout limit is less that 30 seconds in api gateway.so hooking up an sagemaker endpoint with api gateway wouldn't make sense, if the request/response is going to take more than 30 seconds. is there any workaround ? adding a lambda in between api gateway and sagemaker endpoint is going to add more time to process request/response, which i would like to avoid. also, there will be added time for lambda cold starts and sagemaker serverless endpoints are built on top of lambda so that will also add cold start time. is there a way to invoke the serverless sagemaker endpoints , without these overhead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed possible to invoke sagemaker endpoints from sagemaker without using any other AWS services and that is also manifested by the fact that they have invocation URLs.

Here's how you set it up:

1. create an user with only programmatic access and attach a policy json that should look something like below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sagemaker:InvokeEndpoint",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:sagemaker:<region>:<account-id>:endpoint/<endpoint-name>"
        }
    ]
}
```

you can replace `<endpoint-name>` with `*` to let this user invoke all endpoints.

2. use the ACCESS-KEY and SECRET-ACCESS-KEY to configure authorisation in postman like shown in this screenshot. also add the parameters in advanced tab like shown in the screenshot.
   [image]
3. then fill up your body with the relevant content type.
4. then add or remove additional headers like variant-name or model-name, if you have them set up and the headers should look like shown in this screenshot: [image]
5. send the request to receive reponse like this
   [image]

***URL and credentials in the above screenshots doesn't work anymore, duh!***

and if you want code to invoke the endpoint directly using some back-end language, [here's code for python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70803026/11814996).

Comment: thanks. one alternative , i was considering was to integrate api gateway directly to sagemaker endpoints. but only limitations about this approach is that the timeout limit on the API gateway is less than 30 seconds. and the call to sagemaker endpoint can exceed that. any thoughts around this?

Comment: as mentioned here(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html#api-gateway-execution-service-limits-table), AWS API Gateway doesn't allow integration-requests to have greater timeout than 29 seconds. so, you either need to make your sagemaker endpoints faster by adopting parallel processing with something like multiprocessing. so, sagemaker endpoint's 1min timeout also can't be usefule because of API Gateway's limitations for integration requests.

Comment: another option can be to use SageMaker's async invocation, where the maximum timeout is 15 minutes and the results will be pushed to S3. I haven't used it personally though and can't comment on how useful it would be for your use case.

Comment: thanks again. thanks. async option sounds better for my use case. do you know if serverless and async inference work similar , in terms of cost. that we are charged only then the data is processed. with async, how can we queue up our data to be processed

Comment: from what i know from boto3(https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_endpoint_config) and aws innovate sessions, serverless inference is similar to real-time inference except that you don’t get to select the machine you want. and async inference is similar to batch inference, where you don’t receive predictions as response of your HTTP requests.

Answer (score 2):

You can connect SageMaker endpoints to API Gateway directly, without intermediary Lambdas, using *mapping templates* https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/machine-learning/creating-a-machine-learning-powered-rest-api-with-amazon-api-gateway-mapping-templates-and-amazon-sagemaker/

You can also invoke endpoints with AWS SDKs (eg [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker-runtime/invoke-endpoint.html), [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sagemaker-runtime.html#SageMakerRuntime.Client.invoke_endpoint)), no need to do it for API GW necessarily.

Comment: thanks. only thing about this approach was the timeout limit on the API gateway , which seems to be less than 30 seconds.